# TextView blocking click of ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter that creates a list of items. I am trying to make it so clicking anywhere on the list item will do something. However the only clickable area is outside the text area.

Outside the left, right, and top of the red is clickable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJuLm.png

Main Activity XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffd7d7d7">
    <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/cities_list"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

        </FrameLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:background="#ffd7d7d7"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:showDividers="beginning"
        android:background="@drawable/city_list_item_background"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCity"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:editable="false"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class CitiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewCity> {
    public CitiesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewCity> cities) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_city, cities);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




        // get the data item for this position
        NewCity cities = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_city, parent, false);
        }

        // lookup for data population
        TextView tvCity    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);

        TextView tvCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);

        // populate the data into the template view using the ata object
        tvCity.setText(cities.city);
        tvCountry.setText(cities.country);




        // return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity
        extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mMenuItems;

    public static class MyPlacesFragment
            extends Fragment {

        public MyPlacesFragment() {

            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_places, container, false);
            String menu_title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items)[0];

            getActivity().setTitle(menu_title);
            return rootView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //Fragment f0 = new MyPlacesFragment();
        //ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f0);
        //ft.commit();

        populateCitiesList();


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mMenuItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    private void populateCitiesList() {
        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<NewCity> arrayOfUsers = NewCity.getUsers();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        CitiesAdapter adapter = new CitiesAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cities_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                    long id)
            {
                //Tweet theTweet = (Tweet)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                //saved.insert(theTweet);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } );
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" from your listView. If I understand it correctly I believe it's preventing the textview from getting the focus/click and passing it to the parent. Perhaps try setting it to "beforeDescendants".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS

If you can't find a solution that works for you, one work around would be to set an OnClickListener to the textview that performs the same function as the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

you set `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` remove those, try this new:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:showDividers="beginning"
        android:background="@drawable/city_list_item_background"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCity"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:editable="false"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```